# Specific property from object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, object

Lets say i have this object and the first two have the property bought(how many of them the user bought)

```
var Drugs = {
    Extasy : {
        name : "Extasy",
        value: 0,
        bought : 2,
        hist : [],
        qty : 0
    },
    Hash : {
        name : "Hash",
        value: 0,
        hist : [],
        bought: 3,
        qty : 0
    },
    Adrenaline :  {
        name : "Adrenaline",
        value: 0,
        hist : [],
        qty : 0
    },
    Cocaine : {
        name : "Cocaine",
        value: 0,
        hist : [],
        qty : 0
    },
    Mdma : {
        name : "Mdma",
        value: 0,
        hist : [],
        qty : 0
    }
};
```

and i want to loop through the Drugs object in order to find out which of them has the bought property.

```
var outputs = '<li class="ui-li-has-count">';

for (var d in Drugs) {
    var dd = Drugs[d];

    if (Drugs.hasOwnProperty(dd.bought)) {
        // if (dd.bought != 'undefined' ){
        outputs+='<a  class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r" href="#myPopup" onclick="buyPopup(this.id)" id='+dd.name+'  >'+dd.name+'<span  class="ui-li-count">'+dd.bought+'</span> ';
    }
    else {
        outputs = false;
    }

    outputs += '</li></div>';
}

//getElementById
ast("panel1").innerHTML += outputs;
```

Even if my bought key has a property i always get false

Comment: doesn't dd.bought != 'undefined' do the trick ?

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` is a method that only requires the name. So change `dd.bought` to just `'bought'`

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to test the `Drugs` collection, you want to test the individual drug object. Also, `hasOwnProperty` does take the *property name* as a string, not the property value. So use

```
if (dd.hasOwnProperty("bought"))
```

Though in your case, a simple test like

```
if (dd.bought)
```

should suffice, especially as you want to treat non-existing properties (which resolve to `undefined`) just like `0` values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the property "bought", then you need to check for that word in the `hasOwnProperty()` call.  So change this line:

```
if (Drugs.hasOwnProperty(dd.bought)){
```

. . . to this . . .

```
if (dd.hasOwnProperty("bought")){
```

In both of your test items, you are currently checking to see if the item has a property called "2" and "3", respectively, on the "Drugs" object (since that is what `dd.bought` equals at the time you are checking).

You should really also have this in your code before assigning `dd`, as well:

```
if (Drugs.hasOwnProperty(d)){
```

Comment: Problem being with that solution is that testing "Drugs" is testing that level. We need to test dd for the property 'bought', as 'bought' is a dd property, not a Drugs(obj) property.

Comment: Apologies . . . I misread the question.  I've updated my answer.